# How do I activate certain buttons only if checkboxes in a certain table are checked?

Tags: jquery, html

So I have two tables on the same page, and they both have checkboxes. I've defined them both like this:

```
<table class='display' id='table1'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
     **random headers*
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:4px" class="selectChkBox" type="checkbox" id="id1" /></td>
            //random value stuff
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I do this for both of the tables, with table2 having id='table2' and so on. When I check a checkbox next to an item in Table 1 and click on the button 'Move to Table 2', it moves the item to table 2. I want to have the same button for Table 2 where, if I check an item, it would  then proceed to move that item to Table 1.

My problem is, I'm not sure how to do that in the code. Right now, to check if any checkboxes are checked, I have the line:

```
$('.selectChkBox').is(":checked");
```

And if any items are checked, I un-gray out the 'Move to Table 1' and 'Move to Table 2' buttons.

But this makes it so that I can click on the 'Move to Table 2' button if Table 2 items are checked, when I only want to be able to click on the 'Move to Table 1' button. Does anyone know how I can make this check specific to each table? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a more specific selector, one for each table:

For the first table:

```
$('#table1 .selectChkBox').is(":checked");
```

And the second table:

```
$('#table2 .selectChkBox').is(":checked");
```

You could also have an onclick function for the checkboxes, to run whenever someone clicks a box:

```
$("#table1 .selectChkBox').live("click",function() {

    //your code here

});
```

You may not need to have a click function that is specific to each table.  You can simply remove the `#table1` from the selector so that all checkboxes will run the same click function.